# What am I doing wrong with these while loops that I get stuck on the third iteration?

Tags: python

Trying to implement a FSA in python 3.9,

Edit:

For context, this is the first major project I've had to do as a person learning to code. I've been thrown into a uni course about 5 weeks late and have been basically told to try and do what I can to catch up. Im having a lot of trouble figuring out exactly what the looping mechanisms are doing, and class vs variable structure should look like.
[FSA in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekulM.png)
"In this recognizer, the starting state is S1, and S7 is the only accepting state. (Empty strings are not accepted). Your program should ask the user to enter a string and print 'True' if the above FSA accepts it, and "False" otherwise. After printing the result and a 'Goodbye' message the program should immediately stop."

My table showing what the FSA is doing: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuiGo.png)

[I've been trying to keep a github of all my work as well.](https://github.com/Denimbeard/Programing-Classes/tree/main/Python%20Programs/Finite%20State%20Acceptors)

As it checks the digits of the input, it should be testing them against the required steps and either moving backwards or forwards depending on wether or not it meets the requirements. For this example, att should pass the test as the only success.

I've been having trouble getting the loops to work correctly. I can get the first two to happen, but it either gets stuck on the third or doesn't run at all.

```
att = 'bbaccb'


class rec:
    a = 'a'
    b = 'b'
    c = 'c'
    i = 0
    x = 1
    cd = str(att[i])

    def fx():
        rec.x = rec.x + 1
        print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)

    def fi():
        rec.i = rec.i + 1
        print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)

    def bx():
        rec.x = rec.x - 1
        print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)

    def sx():
        rec.x = rec.x + 0
        print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)

    def fail():
        print('False','\n','Goodbye')
        quit()

    def pas():
        print('True\n', 'Goodbye\n')
        quit()

    def forward1():
        rec.fx()
        rec.fi()

    def stepback():
        rec.bx()
        rec.fi()

    def stepback2():
        rec.x = rec.x - 2
        rec.fi()

    def standstill():
        rec.sx()
        rec.fi()
    
    def steps(object): 
        while rec.x > 0:
            print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)
            while rec.x == 1:
                print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)
                if rec.cd == rec.b:
                    rec.forward1()
                if rec.cd == rec.c:
                    rec.forward1()
            else:
                rec.fail()
            
                while rec.x == 2:
                    print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)
                    if rec.cd == rec.a:
                        rec.stepback()
                    if rec.cd == rec.b:
                        rec.forward1()
                else:
                    rec.fail()
                    while rec.x == 3:
                        print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)
                        if rec.cd == rec.a:
                            rec.forward1()
                    else:
                        rec.fail()
                        
                        while rec.x == 4:
                            print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)
                            if rec.cd == rec.a:
                                rec.standstill()
                            if rec.cd == rec.b:
                                rec.stepback()
                            if rec.cd == rec.c:
                                rec.forward1()
                        else:
                            rec.fail()
                            while rec.x == 5:
                                print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)
                                if rec.cd == rec.b:
                                    rec.stepback2()
                                if rec.cd == rec.c:
                                    rec.forward1()
                            else:
                                rec.fail()
                                while rec.x == 6:
                                    print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)
                                    if rec.cd == rec.a:
                                        rec.stepback()
                                    if rec.cd == rec.b:
                                        rec.forward()
                                    if rec.cd == rec.c:
                                        rec.standstill()
                                else:
                                    rec.fail()
                                    while rec.x == 7:
                                            print(rec.i, rec.x, rec.cd)
                                            pas()
        else:
            rec.fail()
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There is virtually no reason you need to nest loops this deeply.

Comment: You don't need `else`. The only way that code *wouldn't* be executed is if you used a `break` statement, and you never do.

Comment: Your `fail()` function quits the program immediately, so it's never going to progress beyond the `while rec.x == 1` loop.  Everything after that point is just dead code.

Comment: This code is literally a Lovecraftian horror and I'm positive what whatever it's supposed to be doing could be implemented in a MUCH shorter way, but none of the variables/functions have meaningful names and there are no comments that give any kind of clue of what the intent is.  Based on your explanation it's not clear why you'd use an FSA at all instead of just checking `==  'bbaccb'`.

Comment: @Samwise Literally?

Comment: @kaya3 LITERALLY.  Azathoth appeared in my Python interpreter when I tried to run it.

Comment: @chepner I am hoping to decode a FSA given to me by a professor and use it with 50 randomly generated strings to produce a fail or pass state, based on the characters in each string fed to it.

Comment: could you share the original FSA that you based this code on?

Comment: I can, just a moment.

Comment: Updated with further context and a link to the FSA in question: @Samwise

Comment: I think it hasn't been said yet...in addition to the logical problems with this code, it has a major syntactic flaw as well.  None of the methods in the defined `rec` class include a `self` parameter, so they're all going to error out at runtime if the execution ever gets to that point.

Answer (score 0):

I sat and looked through it a bit and came up with this as a solution. Im not sure that it's correct, but it does run what I think is the 'password' for this FSA.

```
#==============================================================================
#Variables
#==============================================================================
# Each accepted digit
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 'c'
i = 0
# Placement in attempted string

# Inputed array from the user
arr = input(str('Please enter the string to be recognized: '))

#testing
#arr = 'bbaccb'
#==============================================================================
"""
In this recognizer, the starting state is S1, and S7 is the only accepting state
(empty strings are not accepted). Your program should ask the user to enter a
string and print "True" if the FSA accepts it, "False" otherwise. After printing
the result (and a 'Goodbye' message), the program should immediately stop.
"""

"""
Step 1:
    If arr[i] is an a, fail.
    If b, go to next step with next digit.
    If c, check digit 2
"""
def step1(object):
    global i
    #print(arr[i])
    if arr[i] == a:
        print(false())
    if arr[i] == b:
        forward(object)
        step2(object)
    if arr[i] == c:
        i = i + 1
        step1(object)
    else:
        print(false())
"""
Step 2:
    If arr[i] is an a, return to step 1 with next digit.
    If b, go to next step with next digit.
    If c, fail.
"""
def step2(object):
    global i
    #print(arr[i])
    if arr[i] == a:
        forward(object)
        step1(object)
    if arr[i] == b:
        forward(object)
        step3(object)
    if arr[i] == c:
        print(false())
    else:
        print(false())
"""
Step 3:
    If arr[i] is an a, go to next step with next digit.
    If b, fail.
    If c, fail.
"""
def step3(object):
    global i
    #print(arr[i])
    if arr[i] == a:
        forward(object)
        step4(object)
    if arr[i] == b or c:
        print(false())
    else:
        print(false())
"""
Step 4:
    If arr[i] is an a, check the next digit.
    If b, return to step 3 with the next digit.
    If c, go to next step with next digit.
"""
def step4(object):
    global i
    #print(arr[i])
    if arr[i] == a:
        forward(object)
        step4(object)
    if arr[i] == b:
        forward(object)
        step3(object)
    if arr[i] == c:
        forward(object)
        step5(object)
    else:
        print(false())
"""
Step 5:
    If arr[i] is an a, fail.
    If b, return to step 3 with the next digit.
    If c, go to next step with next digit.
"""
def step5(object):
    global i
    #print(arr[i])
    if arr[i] == a:
        print(fail())
    if arr[i] == b:
        forward(object)
        step3(object)
    if arr[i] == c:
        forward(object)
        step6(object)
    else:
        print(false())
"""
Step 6:
    If arr[i] is an a, return to step 5 with next digit.
    If b, complete task.
    If c, check next digit.
"""
def step6(object):
    global i
    #print(arr[i])
    if arr[i] == a:
        forward(object)
        step5(object)
    if arr[i] == b:
        print(true())
    if arr[i] == c:
        step6(object)
    else:
        print(false())

#If the program compleates the task, then it's 'True'.
def true():
    #print(arr[i])
    print('True.')
    print('Goodbye.')
    quit()

# Otherwise, the arr is 'False'.
def false():
    #print(arr[i])
    print('False.')
    print('Goodbye.')
    quit()

# Move to next item in string
def forward(object):
    global i
    i = i + 1
    #return i
#==============================================================================
# To Do
#==============================================================================
print(step1(arr))
```